# Alternative implementation of pict2e's \Vector

Tags: picture-mode

My implementation of **pict2e** (*Aspose.TeX*) lacks the definition of the `\Vector` command. I tried to implement it with `\put` and `\vector` but I am having problems with nearly vertical vectors (overflow and wrong length).

The `\Line` command is implemented and it's working fine, so a solution could be to create the line part of the vector with it and then add a vector with zero length at the end to draw the arrow head, but this solution has it drawbacks because the line covers the tip of the arrow.

Is there any other way to handle nearly vertical vectors?

Comment: Welcome! You will have a better chance to get help if you post a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/140456) showing what you have and what causes problems

Comment: @LuisTurcio Here is the example: 
https://forum.aspose.com/t/pict2e-package-limitation/266150 
Finally I solved the problem using the \Line command followed by a zero length \vector.

Comment: Glad to hear that you have solved your problem. For future reference try to post a minimal example showing your problem. You can see that your question, as it is, won’t receive any attention from the experts of this site